# 'Stale file handle' error with Vagrant on macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, vagrant, nfs, macos-catalina

After updating macOS to Catalina, Vagrant projects on the external SSD stopped working. Trying access file list in mounted folder gives an error - 'Stale file handle'. At the same time, projects located on the local disk work after adding to the mount path /System/Volumes/Data/. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding '/System/Volumes/Data' only helps for projects on the local file system. And this bug is fixed in last Vagrant version. But the problem is actual for projects on external drives.

I found a not very beautiful, but working solution:

1. Remove old Vagrant lines from /etc/exports and add to /etc/exports:

/Volumes/SSD/DEV/dirname/www -alldirs -mapall=501:20 192.168.33.10

2. sudo nfsd restart
3. showmount -e

You must see correct mount list:
/Volumes/SSD/DEV/dirname/www         192.168.33.10

4. Edit Vagrantfile

config.vm.synced_folder "/Volumes/SSD/DEV/dirname/www", "/var/www", type: "nfs", nfs_export: false

By default vagrant mount your dir to /vagrant folder, but if you want mount in the other dir, add to provision section:
sudo mount -o vers=3,udp 192.168.33.1:/Volumes/SSD/DEV/dirname/www /var/www

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make work by doing:

1 - `sudo rm /etc/exports`

2 - On the Vagrantfile change the configuration on `synced_folder` to use the absolute path in Catalina's new pattern.

ex.: 
`directory = "<project_path>"
config.vm.synced_folder "/System/Volumes/Data#{directory}", "/vagrant", :nfs => true, :mount_options => ['actimeo=2']`

3 - Run `vagrant destroy -f && vagrant up`

And you are good to go!